# Conditions to obtain that the limit of a sequence satisfies the equation of the elememts of the sequence

Tags: real-analysis

If we define by $f_{n}(t)=\int_{0}^{t}g(y,f_{n}(y))dy$ and prove that the limit of $f_{n}$ exists. What do we need to assume about $g$ in order for the limit to satisfy the above integral equation aswell? In other words,

$f(t)=\int_{0}^{t}g(y,f(y))dy$

Comment: If $g$ is continuous and bounded, you can apply the dominated convergence theorem to get $f(t) = \int_0^t g(y,f(y)) \, \mathrm{d} y$.

Comment: @p4sch thanks, do you know if pointwise convergence of $f_{n}$? Or does it need to be uniform.

Comment: Pointwise convergence is sufficient.

Comment: @p4sch right, we just think about it as $g_{n}$ essentially to use dominated. Then continuity to get the limit inside $g$?

Comment: Yes. (In fact, you can weaken the assumptation by $g(x,y)$ is measurable in $x$ for fixed $y$ and continuous in $y$ for fixed $x$.)